# Google plus api "Resource object has no attribute 'insert' "

Tags: python, google-api-python-client, google-domain-api, google-plus-domains

Following the directions found on google developers [here](https://developers.google.com/+/domains/posts/creating)

when I try to add an activity (a post) I get a python error

```
"Resource object has no attribute 'insert' "
```

but when I look [here](https://developers.google.com//resources/api-libraries/documentation/plusDomains/v1/python/latest/) (at the api docs) there's clearly a *insert* method under *activities()*

this is the problem code

```
result = service.activities().insert(
                userId=user_id,
                body={
                   'object': {
                        #'orginalContent': content 
                    },
                    'access': {
                        'items': [{
                            'type': 'domain'
                        }],
                        'domainRestricted': True
                    }
                }).execute()
```

I handled all the authentication stuff before of course, the code above is taken from google's example
And I have the proper scope(s) included, I can't for the life of me figure out the problem...

Anyone have experience with this??

or is anyone able to successfully run google's example code? would be a lot of help to know thanks

*also forgot to mention this is in a django view if that makes a difference

Comment: Make sure using the latest version of the client library

Comment: yeah, checked and everything is up to date

Comment: @Reed Did you created service object with build('plusDomains', 'v1', http=http)? Examples on this website does not show full code.